# How to compare the current data to the next data in the SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, mysql

I have this table:

```
 ID
00001
00001
00002
00002
00003
00004
00004
00004
00005
```

If the `SqlDataReader` reaches the 5th column *(which is the `00003`)*, is there a possibility that I can compare whether the next one has the same `ID` as the current value before finishing the current `while` loop?

I will be using this to determine whether the reader will move to the next different `ID`, so that I can draw the controls for the last part, then move on for the next `ID`.

I would love to post the code but since I'm creating elements dynamically, it is very long.

**EDIT:**

Here is the code *(cleaned to make it simple as possible)*:

```
bool isFinished = false;
string lastID = "";
while (reader.Read())
{
    string transID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ID"]).ToString("D5");
    lastID = (lastID == "") ? transID : lastID;
    isFinished = (lastID != transID) ? true : false;
    if (isFinished)
    {
        LastPart();
    }
    initialParts();

    lastID = transID;   
}
```

With this codes, I managed to put the `LastPart()` after all the data with similar `ID` has been created. But this results in the `LastPart()` not being called after the last `initialParts()`

Comment: If it is me, I will think it the other way round: read the current line and compare with the previous, if different, call `initialParts()`, otherwise, call `LastPart()`. Cache the previous results and draw respectively, rather than draw first then compare.

Comment: @Tide Gu Hmmm,I'll try this logic.Thank you

Comment: @TideGu What do you mean by this part: `Cache the previous results and draw respectively, rather than draw first then compare.`?

Answer (score 0):

Here ist a Sample in SQL. In the **union ALL** section you can pu your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT @my_id:=@my_last_id AS new_id , @my_last_id:=id AS next_id
   FROM
     ( SELECT *
      FROM
        ( SELECT *
         FROM
           ( SELECT "00001" AS id
            UNION ALL SELECT "00001"
            UNION ALL SELECT "00002"
            UNION ALL SELECT "00002"
            UNION ALL SELECT "00003"
            UNION ALL SELECT "00004"
            UNION ALL SELECT "00004"
            UNION ALL SELECT "00004"
            UNION ALL SELECT "00005" ) AS yourTable
         UNION ALL SELECT NULL AS id ) tablePlusOneRow) newTable
   CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @my_id:=NULL, @my_next_id:=NULL) init) AS new_table2
WHERE new_id IS NOT NULL;
```

**sample**

```
MariaDB [sample]> SELECT *
    -> FROM
    ->   (SELECT @my_id:=@my_last_id AS new_id , @my_last_id:=id AS next_id
    ->    FROM
    ->      ( SELECT *
    ->       FROM
    ->         ( SELECT *
    ->          FROM
    ->            ( SELECT "00001" AS id
    ->             UNION ALL SELECT "00001"
    ->             UNION ALL SELECT "00002"
    ->             UNION ALL SELECT "00002"
    ->             UNION ALL SELECT "00003"
    ->             UNION ALL SELECT "00004"
    ->             UNION ALL SELECT "00004"
    ->             UNION ALL SELECT "00004"
    ->             UNION ALL SELECT "00005" ) AS yourTable
    ->          UNION ALL SELECT NULL AS id ) tablePlusOneRow) newTable
    ->    CROSS JOIN
    ->      (SELECT @my_id:=NULL, @my_next_id:=NULL) init) AS new_table2
    -> WHERE new_id IS NOT NULL;
+--------+---------+
| new_id | next_id |
+--------+---------+
| 00001  | 00001   |
| 00001  | 00002   |
| 00002  | 00002   |
| 00002  | 00003   |
| 00003  | 00004   |
| 00004  | 00004   |
| 00004  | 00004   |
| 00004  | 00005   |
| 00005  | NULL    |
+--------+---------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sample]>
```

**speed with 1000000 ROWS**

The time includes also tho time for the output 0.28 / 0.79 sec

```
MariaDB [sample]> select * from myids;

.....
|  999998 |
|  999999 |
| 1000000 |
+---------+
1000000 rows in set (0.28 sec)

MariaDB [sample]>

    SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT @my_id:=@my_last_id AS new_id , @my_last_id:=id AS next_id
    FROM (
        SELECT * 
        FROM (
        SELECT * 
        FROM (
            SELECT * FROM myids
        ) AS yourTable
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT NULL AS id
        ) tablePlusOneRow
    ) newTable
    CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @my_id:=NULL, @my_next_id:=NULL) init
    ) AS new_table2
    WHERE new_id IS NOT NULL;

    ....
    |  999998 |  999999 |
    |  999999 | 1000000 |
    | 1000000 |    NULL |
    +---------+---------+
    1000000 rows in set (0.79 sec)
```

Comment: It seems to be a good solution on small tables, but I'm worrying about the performance on huge tables or concurrent queries.

Comment: @Tide Gu - The whole is very very fast, since only one line is appended and the result is only output from the 2 row

Comment: Thanks. I don't know too much details, but the gut feeling is that there are many selects and temporary tables, that's why I was worrying. The test shows (assumingly) only few fields, if there are tens or hundreds of fields, will it become slow? And nearly 2.5x slower than single select seems a bit slow to me - your solution answers the OP's question, but to me, I would reconsider the logic as my first comment. Thanks :p

Comment: @BerndBuffen Is this part (`@my_id:=@my_last_id AS new_id , @my_last_id:=id AS next_id`) as is?Or should I replace it with the column name? Except for the table name, I really don't know what other things to be replaced

Comment: @BerndBuffen I can't seem to make this work, I understood some of the parts, but overall I still get errors.